# Fade-in a control in when a view is loaded (and not inserted after a state change)

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, fadein

What I’m after is for a control to be faded in when the view it’s contained in appears for the *first* time. I’ve tried everything but have had no luck.

```
withAnimation(.default) {
    Text("hey")
        .transition(.opacity)
}   

// as well as

Text("hey")
    .transition(.opacity)
    .animation(.default)

// and finally

@State var opacity:Double = 0.0
Text("hey")
    .opacity(self.opacity)
    .transition(.opacity)
    .animation(.default)
[...]
.onAppear() {
    self.opacity = 1.0
}
```

I can get the animation to work if the view is made visible via a button press that changes the value of the self.opacity, and I imagine the above methods would work in general if the control isn’t meant to appear initially but gets inserted instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible solution (you can tune parameters to have desired effect)

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoFadeInView: View {
    @State var isShown = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if isShown {
                Text("hey")
                     .transition(.opacity)
            }
        }
         .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1).delay(0.5))  // delay is optional, for demo
        .onAppear() {
             self.isShown.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Asperi! But what about when there are multiple controls? Having the animation modifier on the root container control means all children are being animated into view too. And when I tried to apply the modifier just to the Text control, it wasn't working.

Comment: 1) you can link animation by specific value using `.animation(_, value:)`; 2) do not apply animation to root view, but separate by small subviews with own animation. ... and, btw, this is out of scope of initial question ;)

Comment: 2) did the trick! Basically what you proposed in your original solution, applied to whatever control I want by moving it to be its own subview. I'm curious about your recommendation 1) though. Is that an alternative way? I’m not sure how you can link between the modifier’s value and the control in the hierarchy I want to animate on. Clarification would be appreciated!